# Bootstrap tooltip has a white background

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my html file I'm trying to add tooltip to icons when they are hovered over. But I see white background or a border along with tool tip. Its shown as a simple tooltip in jsfiddle but I can see it more styled along with with background. I want to remove that white background as shown in picture.

http://jsfiddle.net/azsLk03y/3/`

```
<div class="container ">
</div>
<div class="row  margins ">
    <a href="#" class="">
        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" ></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="">
        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Preview" ></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="">
        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Email"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="">
        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" ></span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

[Thats how I see it in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ0C7.png)

Comment: I see no tooltip at all in your fiddle

Comment: there is no white background. see here http://jsfiddle.net/azsLk03y/4/. some conflict of css on your website

Comment: Yeah it looks like conflict with website. Thanks man.

Comment: Check your HTML code, it has syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap you have some conflict with the tooltip class. That is not the default tooltip of Bootstrap.

Search it in your generated css code.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Default tooltip">you probably</a>
```

[Bootstrap Tooltip Example](https://codepen.io/tipsoftheday/pen/igKoF)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your .css file

```css
.tooltip-inner{
  background-color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue with easyui.css doing its own tooltip stuff. I had to make it show and set its background to transparent to get rid of the white.

```
    .tooltip{
        border:0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        display:inline-block !important;
    }
```